# Irreducible languages

Tags: fl.formal-languages

This is not necessarily a research question. Just a question out of curiosity:

I am trying to understand if one can define "irreducible" languages.
As a first guess I call a language L "reducible" if it can be written as
$L = A \cdot B$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $|A|,|B|>1$, otherwise call the language "irreducible". Is it true:

1) If P is irreducible, A,B, C are languages such that $A\cap B = \emptyset$, $P \cap C = \emptyset$ and $A\cdot B = C\cdot P$, then there exists a language $B' \cap P = \emptyset$ such that $B = B'\cdot P$? This would correspond in integers to the lemma of Euklid and would be usefull to prove uniqueness of "factorization".

2) Is it true that every language can be factored in a *finite* number of irreducible languages?

If someone has a better idea on how to define "irreducible" language, I would like to hear it. (Or is there maybe already a definiton of this, which I am unaware of?)

Comment: "if it can be written as
$L = A \cdot B$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $|A|,|B|>1$," where ​ $\cdot$ ​ is ... ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: $\cdot$ is concatenation

Comment: You may be interested in the paper "Prime Languages", although it is a different notion: http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~ornak/publications/mfcs13.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a counterexample to this:

> call a language L "reducible" if it can be written as
>   $L = A \cdot B$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $|A|,|B|>1$, otherwise call the language "irreducible". Is it true:
>
> 1) If P is irreducible, A,B, C are languages such that $A\cap B = \emptyset$, $P \cap C = \emptyset$ and $A\cdot B = C\cdot P$, then there exists a language $B' \cap P = \emptyset$ such that $B = B'\cdot P$?

In the unary alphabet $\{0\}$, define the following words
$$a=0^4,\quad b=0,\qquad c=0^3,\quad p=0^2.$$
Then $ab=cp$ and it is not the case that $b=b'p$ for any $b'$.

So we get a counterexample with the singleton languages
$$P=\{p\},\quad A=\{a\},\quad B=\{b\},\quad C=\{c\}.$$

Comment: @bjornkjoshanssen: Thank you for your example and your answer!

Comment: @orgesleka You're welcome... I guess concatenation is more like addition than like multiplication

Answer (score 18):

There is the notion of primality of a language. It asks whether L can be written as $L_1 \cdot L_2$ where neither factor contains the empty word. A language is prime if it cannot be written in this form.

For a given regular language, represented by a DFA, it is shown in [MNS] that it is PSPACE-complete to decide primality.

[MNS] Wim Martens, Matthias Niewerth and Thomas Schwentick,
"[Schema design for XML repositories: complexity and tractability](http://www.theoinf.uni-bayreuth.de/download/Schema_Design_for_XML_Repositories.pdf)", 2010. [doi:10.1145/1807085.1807117](http://doi.org/10.1145/1807085.1807117)

Answer (score 14):

Another paper to look at:

- Kai Salomaa, "[Language Decompositions, Primality, and Trajectory-Based Operations](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-70844-5_2)", 2008.